# why can't I log in to django admin

Tags: python, django, admin

So yesterday I installed Python/Django on to my computer using these commands

```
ls
cd desktop
ls
Sudo easy_install pip
Sudo pip install virtualenv
Virtualenv tryTen
Ls
Cd tryTen
Source bin/activate
Pip freeze
Ls
pip install Django==1.10
pip freeze
django-admin.py startproject tryTen
ls
cd tryTen
ls
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
Ls
python manage.py runserver
```

The admin page eventually popped up and I was able to log in successfully. After I was done I pressed control + c and closed the window. I figured I would just start off from where I finished yesterday. But to my surprise when I tried to log in a few minutes ago using python manage.py createsuperuser I was told the file does not exist on my computer, but the file is right here. I also entered http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ into the search bar, but it can't be reached.

I must be doing something wrong, but what is it? I'm confused. Do I have to write in all those commands again just to log in? Please help.

Comment: You shouldn't have to run `createsuperuser` again. The super user you created yesterday should still be there. And you'll only be able to browse to your site's URL when it's running. Typically in development that's done via `python manage.py runserver`. When you pressed Ctrl+C you stopped it; you'll need to start it again by running that command from your virtualenv.

Comment: I'm guessing that you didnt start the virtual environment.

Comment: You don't need use all the commands again. You will need the `Source bin/activate` (at the folder *~/desktop/tryTen*, for activate your old virtualenv) and `python manage.py runserver` (at the folder *~/desktop/tryTen/tryTen*). The first command will [activate your script](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) and the second will [start the local server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#runserver)

Comment: try run: `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: @eyllanesc, how would _that_ help?